# Yum still looking for an old proxy

Tags: yum, http-proxy

Our firewall and gateway team installed new proxy servers last week, and I updated the proxy information both in `/root/.bash_profile` and in `/etc/yum.conf`.

However, `strace -f yum -v clean all` shows that `yum` is still trying to connect to the old, shut down proxy.

Did I miss a hidden configuration file, somewhere?

Comment: `sudo grep -r proxyaddress /etc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the setting `httpProxy` in `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date`!